# Why is this code deleting the contents of previous XML tags?

Tags: c++, xml, openframeworks

This is [openFrameworks](http://openframeworks.cc) C++ code. It's saving information about each move made in a game, but each new game wipes out all of the values inside `<MOVE> <PLAYER/> <MOVE/>` for any previous `<GAME><GAME/>` tags.

```
bool My_xml::setup() {
  XML.loadFile(ofxiPhoneGetDocumentsDirectory() + "scoresAndSettings.xml")

  //read the settings from XML
  //if the settings file doesn't exist we assign default values

  globalsettings.user_id = XML.getValue("GLOBALSETTINGS:USERID", ofRandom(std::numeric_limits<float>::max() - 1));
  if (globalsettings.user_id == 0) { // for first game only
    XML.setValue("GLOBALSETTINGS:USERID", globalsettings.user_id);
  }
  globalsettings.playing_big_board = XML.getValue("GLOBALSETTINGS:BIGBOARD", false);
  globalsettings.drawCrossHairs = XML.getValue("GLOBALSETTINGS:DRAWCROSSHAIRS", false);
  globalsettings.graphFFT = XML.getValue("GLOBALSETTINGS:GRAPHFFT", true); //
  globalsettings.showDebugText = XML.getValue("GLOBALSETTINGS:SHOWDEBUGTEXT", false);

  gameNumber = XML.addTag("GAME");
  XML.setAttribute("GAME", "number", gameNumber+1, gameNumber);
  XML.setAttribute("GAME", "start", makeTimeStamp(), gameNumber);
  XML.pushTag("GAME", gameNumber);

  return true;
}

void My_xml::saveMoveInfo() {
  int moveNumber    = XML.addTag("MOVE");
  if( XML.pushTag("MOVE", moveNumber) ){
    // put in data from this move
    int player = ((testApp*)ofGetAppPtr())->gameplay->whoseTurnIsIt;
    string playerTag = "PLAYER " + ofToString(player);
    int tagNum = XML.addTag(playerTag);
    XML.addAttribute(playerTag, "move", moveNumber++, tagNum);
    XML.addAttribute(playerTag, "duration", lastMoveDuration, tagNum);
    XML.addAttribute(playerTag, "wait", waitBeforeThisMove, tagNum);
    XML.addAttribute(playerTag, "timestamp", makeTimeStamp(), tagNum);
    XML.popTag();
  }

  XML.saveFile( ofxiPhoneGetDocumentsDirectory() + "scoresAndSettings.xml" );
}

void My_xml::winGame() {
  writeToFile();
}

void My_xml::writeToFile() {
  XML.popTag();
  XML.setAttribute("GAME", "lat", ofToString(coreLocation->getLatitude(), 10), gameNumber);
  XML.setAttribute("GAME", "long", ofToString(coreLocation->getLongitude(), 10), gameNumber);
  XML.setAttribute("GAME", "end", makeTimeStamp(), gameNumber);
  XML.saveFile( ofxiPhoneGetDocumentsDirectory() + "scoresAndSettings.xml" );
}
```

**EDIT/Addition:** This code, which stores calibration data, **doesn't** get overwritten/cleared/eaten each game.

```
  if (animations->training != NOT_TRAINING) {
    int numGameTags = XML.XML.getNumTags("GAME");
    XML.XML.pushTag("GAME", numGameTags-1);
    int moveNumber  = XML.XML.addTag("CALIBRATION");

    if (gameplay->whoseTurnIsIt < 2) { // PLAYER 1
      switch (animations->training) {
        case TRAINING_UP:
          XML.player1settings.pitch_high = gameplay->high_pitch_thresh;
          XML.XML.setAttribute("CALIBRATION", "player", gameplay->whoseTurnIsIt, moveNumber);
          XML.XML.setAttribute("CALIBRATION", "type", "pitch", moveNumber);
          XML.XML.setAttribute("CALIBRATION", "level", "high", moveNumber);
          XML.XML.setValue("CALIBRATION", gameplay->high_pitch_thresh, moveNumber);
          break;
        // etc.
        default:
          break;
      } 
    } else { // PLAYER 2
      switch (animations->training) {
        case TRAINING_UP:
          XML.player2settings.pitch_high = gameplay->high_pitch_thresh;
          XML.XML.setAttribute("CALIBRATION", "player", gameplay->whoseTurnIsIt, moveNumber);
          XML.XML.setAttribute("CALIBRATION", "type", "pitch", moveNumber);
          XML.XML.setAttribute("CALIBRATION", "level", "high", moveNumber);
          XML.XML.setValue("CALIBRATION", gameplay->high_pitch_thresh, moveNumber);
          break;
        // etc.
        default:
          break;
      } // end switch
    } // end else
    XML.XML.popTag();
  }
```

**EDIT 2:**
I just noticed that the XML tags are actually being altered, not just having the contents removed. Note that the tag is `<PLAYER 1>` or `<PLAYER 2>` in the most recent game, but just `<PLAYER />` in all the old data...

```
<GAME number="3" start="2011-08-19|16:00:59|2.7" lat="51.38325077" long="-2.36163312" end="2011-08-19|16:01:29|32.8">
    <PLAYER />
</GAME>
<GAME number="4" start="2011-08-19|16:14:12|2.6">
    <PLAYER />
</GAME>
<GAME number="5" start="2011-08-19|16:16:10|2.9">
    <PLAYER 1 col="0" row="2" err="0" move="1" duration="0.012999" wait="19.784000" timestamp="2011-08-19|16:16:30|22.8"></PLAYER 1>
    <PLAYER 2 col="0" row="2" err="-2" move="1" duration="0.219000" wait="1.605001" timestamp="2011-08-19|16:16:32|24.6"></PLAYER 2>
    <PLAYER 2 col="0" row="2" err="-2" move="2" duration="0.226000" wait="1.500000" timestamp="2011-08-19|16:16:34|26.4"></PLAYER 2>
</GAME>
```

**EDIT3**: Aaaaand that's it. No spaces in a tag name. Sheesh.

Comment: SO-etiquette-wise, what do we think? @ben has given me some good code cleanup, but his answer isn't really exactly quite *the* answer. I'd like to accept it especially because I feel a sort of between-100-and-200 camaraderie, but on the other hand I don't want to go against what an 'accepted' answer is supposed to be about. Anyone? Am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML tags can't have spaces in them.

`<PLAYER 1>` tags were getting eaten when the file was reopened, regardless of whatever my code was doing to it.

`<PLAYER1>` is fine, and fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

are you shure that gamenumber is the same in `setup()` and `writeToFile()` ?
Is your XML File written correctly after one save?
Also be shure to be in the right tags with `pushTag()` and `popTag()`. Its better to do this straight before you use the tag. So if I'm understanding your code right `writeToFile()` has to be called directly after `setup()` because you push to your Game Node already in `setup()`. I would  try to fix that and would make a parameter to writeToFile with the Game ID.

Comment: Good advice! Still eating all previous `<"MOVE">` data with each new game, though. Noting new details in original post.

Comment: try pushing to game tags like in your second code snippet in line 2 and 3. I'm not sure if ofxXmlSettings get it right if there are already tags with this name in a previously written xml file. again: is your xml written right for the first time?

Comment: GameNumber definitely staying the same. XML looks good the first time it's written. Trying to rework the `pushTag()` strategy now...